# How to show label on custom icon image in google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am now working on GoogleMap and trying to show label on custom icon image as below.

```
var image = {
        url: "{% static "img/perch_logo_blue.png" %}",
        size: new google.maps.Size(45,45),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,32),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20)
    };

    var shape = {
        coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
        type: 'poly'
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < perches.length; i++) {
        var perch = perches[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: perch[1], lng: perch[2]},
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          label: '5',
          title: perch[0]
        });
    }
```

The problem is that the label is not on icon, but beside of icon image as below.

[image]

So I hope to know how to show label with white color on blue icon image.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The color(and e.g. fontSize and fontFamily) may be set via the [`label`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon)-property of the marker:

Example for a white 5:

```
label:{text:'5',color:'white'}
```

The position of the label may be set via the `labelOrigin`-property of the [`icon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon)

It's not clear how the original image looks like, you'll need to play around a little bit to find the best value for the `labelOrigin`(it's expected to be a `google.maps.Point` ).

Demo:

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 20,
      center: {
        lat: 52.5498783,
        lng: 13.425209099999961
      }
    }),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      map: map,
      icon: {
        url: 'http://i.imgur.com/YsKYfOw.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(45, 45),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 20),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(9, 8)
      },
      label: {
        text: '5',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '12px',
        fontFamily: '"Courier New", Courier,Monospace',
        color: 'white'
      }
    });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**Note:** in your example the value of the `anchor`-property seems to be incorrect.
I guess the tail of the marker should point to the desired location.
When the end of the tail  is in the bottom-left corner of the image, the anchor should be `(0,scaledHeightOfTheImage)`